# autocreate collection and type of creation

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a simple example:

```
conn = Connection()
db = conn.livestat
coll = db.cmn1
coll.insert({'test': 1 });
```

before insert collection autocreate. How to disable this function or add param to autocreate  (for example I want to create a capped collection ) ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do it manually. See [the doc](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/createCollection+Command).

```
db.createCollection("cmn1", {capped:true, size:100000})
```

Answer (score 1):

You must create the capped collection before you write to it for the first time. Please use this function:

http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.create_collection